# Do recruiters get paid for placing candidates for interview who don't accept offer?

Tags: interviewing, salary, recruitment, human-resources

Companies or candidates can be picky for some positions to fill so hiring may take long time. If recruiter places candidate who passes all interview stages but declines offer. Do recruiters get payment for the search expenses? Or just for successfully hired?
It definitely depends on specific agreement but what's common practice?

Comment: Generally, when I was a recuiter, recruiters are paid for candidates who become employees, with a replace or refund guarantee if they don't last three months. My contingency was based on the expected first year's compensation for that candidate (meaning, if there was a bonus component, we'd calculate based on expected bonus achieved, if successful at the job). So, I guess, technically, a candidate who refused an offer I could still get "paid" for, but since their expected first year's compensation would be zero, it would be a mute point.

Comment: Question was held as off topic, citing "Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department.  Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals"  But the actual question is **specifically not** company-specific, and is not a legal question.  Question should be re-opened.

Comment: A retained recruiter gets paid in advance, they’re committed to getting the candidate you need. - https://www.recruiter.com/i/retained-vs-contingency-recruiting-which-one-is-right-for-you/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do recruiters get payment for this?

In my professional experience, a recruiter or recruiting company only get's paid **if the candidate is placed**.

In addition, most companies will have a rider of some kind stating that the new employee has to stay on with the company for *X* amount of time before they are paid at all.

The other approach I have seen companies take is that they will pay the amount due to the recruiter over multiple payments over a time span.  For example, they may get the amount in thirds every 4 months.  This way all the money is not paid before the new hire sticks around.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the specific agreement! Between two business-partners almost anything is possible.

I don´t know what is common, but I know of several occasions where they only got a bounty if a candidate was actually hired.